# Where clause with a dangling comma in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I'm following a Python tutorial at [W3school](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_where.asp).

```py
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address LIKE %s"
adr = ("Yellow Garden 2", )        // I don't understand this part!!!

mycursor.execute(sql, adr) 

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
    print(x)
```

If I run the above code, I get the following result.
[image]

However when I remove a blank space after a comma, I get an error.
`adr = ("Yellow Garden 2", )` --> `adr = ("Yellow Garden 2" )`

**1) I want to know why I need a blank space after a comma.**

**2) Why do I need a bracket ( ) ,too?** (When I remove the brackets, I also get an error.) Like `adr = "Yellow Garden 2"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
adr = ("Yellow Garden 2", )
```

This defines `adr` to be a `tuple` with a single element. You can verify with:

```
type(adr)
```

Should be:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

When you remove the comma `,` (it's the comma that's causing it, not the blank space), `adr` becomes a simple string:

```
adr = ("Yellow garden 2")
type(adr)
```

Should be:

```
<type 'str'>
```

The MySQL API expects a `tuple` to be passed as arguments, hence the error. And the `(soemthing,)` is just how you define single-element tuples in python.

Answer (score 2):

I based this answer off [this blog post](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2232993.html).  The second parameter to `execute` is a *tuple*, and a dangling comma is required, but *only* if the tuple has just one element in it.  As the blog discusses, the dangling comma is required to distinguish:

```
("Yellow Garden 2",)
```

the tuple, from:

```
("Yellow Garden 2")
```

the literal string expression.  Or, at least `(1)` would be ambiguous as to whether you intended for it to be a tuple or arithmetic expression.

However, in the case of two or more parameters, the dangling comma should be optional, e.g.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address LIKE %s OR address LIKE %s"
adr = ("Yellow Garden 1", "Yellow Garden 2")
mycursor.execute(sql, adr)
```

**Edit:**

I will add also that it might be considered best programming practice to *always* use the dangling comma in a tuple here.  Why?  Let's say you authored some code which initially used a tuple with two elements in it.  You would technically not need the dangling comma.  But then, in the future, someone might refactor and remove one element.  If you had *not* included the dangling comma, then the code might break.

Answer (score 1):

This happend  because the example use a tuple  ( ...,)  for passing a value
the value  adr = ("Yellow Garden 2", )     is a tuple that contain a single value

if you need  just  string you coudl try

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE address LIKE concat('%', %s, '%')"

adr = "Yellow Garden 2"
mycursor.execute(sql, adr)
```

or

```
mycursor.execute(sql, "Yellow Garden 2")
```